# Why can I see login credentials sent via HTTPS on my proxy server?

Tags: asp.net, https, proxy

I've got a login page that uses HTTPS, however when I submit the credentials and intercept the request with the webscarab proxy sever, I can see the credentials in plain text, similar to the the second example in this OWASP [article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_credentials_transport_%28OWASP-AT-001%29)

Am I misunderstanding how HTTPS/Webscarab works? If I am intercepting a request being sent via HTTPS, shouldn't the login credentials be encrypted in the request by the time the proxy server intercepts them?

Comment: The whole idea of intercepting SSL by a proxy is that proxy DECRYPTS the traffic and ENCRYPTS it again when forwarding to the server. The data is then available as plain text at the proxy side. And because your browser sends plain text, you see the plain text in your proxy.

Comment: So can't an attacker just set up a proxy in between my browser and the server? Thereby viewing my credentials in plain text?

Comment: Yes, obviously he CAN. The only thing that he CAN't do is he can't match the SSL certificate of the server. He will always be using his own certificate so you, as a client, making the connection will see WRONG certificate of the server (it will be the attacker's certificate). This is why the trust can only be established if you trust the certificate. If you don't pay attention to the certificate, anyone can pretend to be the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, WebScarab is intended to be used as an *explicit* proxy, ie the browser must be purposefully configured to connect to it. At this point, the SSL handshake happens between the browser and WebScarab, so obviously WebScarab can read the data in clear text (you can think of it as the browser is instructed to thread WebScarab as the target host for each and every HTTP request)

Things work differently when you don't set up a proxy by yourself. In this case, the SSL handshake is performed between you and the *target* host, so it doesn't matter how many intermediate agents your HTTP request passes through, it can only be deciphered by the right one

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! So out of curiosity if I am using an explicit proxy such as webscarab, does the request then get re-encrypted before being sent out to the server?

Comment: I *hope* so :P However, even in the case of an imaginary oversimplified proxy forwarding all requests on plain sockets, a properly configured webapp would just refuse the connection (for example a particular URL/URL pattern is marked as available on SSL only)

Comment: You can always install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see what really goes on on the wire

Comment: Will do. Thanks!
So hypothetically, if an attacker knew that I was using an explicit proxy on port XXXX and my browser was configured for such, could he then set up an another proxy using the same port XXXX to intercept the data and view it in plain text? So the request goes from mybrowser to my proxy, then from my proxy to the attackers proxy, then from the attackers proxy to the server.

Comment: No! A connection (a socket) is *srcip:srcport:dstip:dstport:proto* You configure a proxy bu supplying an *ip:port* pair, and hopefully that machine is under **your control**! Why do you think your proxy should connect to the malicious one instead of the target host?